# How to write CSS for shipping method description in WooCommerce (woo-pack Cart)

Tags: css, woocommerce

I have a short description included with a shipping method option for local pickup, but approval is required in order to select that option. The description includes the email address for approval. Is it possible to write CSS to make just the email address a different color and/or hyperlink? I've attached a screenshot with the inspector tool, if that's helpful. I'm not sure how to make just the email address within this block different so it stands out.
[Screenshot of description block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBmqx.png)

I tried making an edit directly within the text editor/setup of this description, but that wasn't an option. Because it is a field pulled from the shipping settings, I cannot edit it with the Beaver Builder editing tools.

Comment: Please provide debugging details in the form of a [repro]. Images are neither an acceptable not suitable substitute to provide code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without wrapping the element in some kind of a container. As it is an email, you should wrap it in an anchor and add a `href="mailto:"` to it. This makes screen readers recognize it as an email and you can click on it to open your default email program.

If wrapped in a container you can use CSS to reference the email link by using `a[href^="mailto:"]`. That selector will check if an `href` attribute starts with the `mailto` prefix.

```css
a[href^="mailto:"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Louisville, KY - This option is only available if prior arrangements have been made - email <a href="mailto:nan@taboodoir.com">nan@taboodoir.com</a> for approval. If selected incorrectly, your order will be placed on hold and we will contact you to resubmit.</p>
```